# Is there a function in CodeIgniter to get all rows of the database query result as single array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there a function in CodeIgniter to get all rows of the database query result as single array, rather than a resource that has to be iterated. Sometimes all rows in one array is all one needs.

Something like:

```
$this->db->query("MULTI-ROW QUERY")->all_rows();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
$new_array = $this->db->query("MULTI-ROW QUERY")->result_array();
print_r($new_array);
```

Go through the following link for detail: 
[Generating Query Results](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: Right, had to sleep the night before. I got it now that I've read the source of the function. While all the guys here are right. You deserve to have a check mark for detailed clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

`$this->db->get(TABLE)` will return all rows from TABLE

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
//here the $rows will be an array
$rows = $query->result_array ();
```